# VisualVM results differ from manual measurements

Tags: java, visualvm, execution-time

I am using Eclipse with plugin for running VisualVM. Now the VisualVM says that the method call of a function returns always around 180ms, while if I use manual method:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
searchConnections(bsTree, connectionList);
double elapsedTimeInSec = (System.nanoTime() - start) * 1.0e-6;
```

I get around 50ms! Why is there a difference? So are the measurements in VisualVM wrong? I need measurements for some project that is why it is important that they are as precised as they can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, there isn't an easy way to know why exactly the values are different because of the nature of the JVM and how it will optimize code during runtime. Not to mention System.nanotime() is a platform specific implementation and I wouldn't fully trust its value for anything accurate.

I would be more likely to trust the result from VisualVM over the inline measurements simply because VisualVM is actually measuring it. If you are concerned about benchmarking or want to really focus on getting accurate results I would suggest using a tool such as [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) for this task.